# Growing XFS filesystem on AWS in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, xfs

I have an EBS volume that originally was 1 Tb:

```
# df -h | grep data
/dev/xvdcl     1000G   54G  946G   6% /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

I then grew it to 3 Tb via the AWS console. Now I want to grow the fs on that volume. First I check the mount point and fs type:

```
# mount | grep xfs
/dev/xvdcl on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

But when I run `xfs_growfs` it tells me it is not actually mounted:

```
# xfs_growfs -d /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
xfs_growfs: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data is not a mounted XFS filesystem
```

Could this be because I'm doing it from inside of a docker container running under kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it had something to do with docker. When I logged in to the actual node and ran `xfs_growfs` it worked as expected.